$R = \left\{(x, y) : |x+y|<2\right\}$ is transitive relation or not on $(-1,1)$
Let $R$ be a relation on the open interval $(-1, 1)$ and is given by $R = \left\{(x, y) : |x+y|<2\right\}$. Then how to prove or discard transitive relation?
If $R = \left\{(x, y) : |x-y|<2\right\}$ then I easily check the transitivity but in $R = \left\{(x, y) : |x+y|<2\right\}$, I don't understand how to proceed this problem. Please help me.

Doesn't $R$ contain all possible pairs $(x,y)$ from $(-1,1)$? And hence it must be transitive?

I couldn't understand what you say

The transitivity holds because $|a + b| < 2$ for every $a\in(-1,1)$ and $b\in(-1,1)$.
Indeed, suppose otherwise that $|a + b| \geq 2$ for some $a\in(-1,1)$ and $b\in(-1,1)$.
This implies that $|a| + |b| \geq 2$, which is not possible because $|a| < 1$ and $|b| < 1$.
In other words, $|a + b| < 2$ for every $a\in(-1,1)$ and $b\in(-1,1)$.
In particular, if $|x + y| < 2$ and $|y + z| < 2$, then $|x + z| < 2$ for every $\{x,y,z\}\subset(-1,1)$.
Hopefully this helps!
